# Mean Value Theorem and an Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

First of all, I would like to say I am following [MIT's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPl-7_RL0Ko&index=16&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63ctJIEC1UnZ0btsphnnoHR) at 52:00.

Assume $f$ is continuously differentiable. They say that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(f(t_{i+1})-f(t_{i}))^{2}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}((f'(s_{i})(t_{i+1}-t_{i}))^{2}
$$
by the mean value theorem where $s_{i}\in[t_{i},t_{i+1}].$ Why? I see
that the mean value theorem gives us
$$
f'(s_{i})(t_{i+1}-t_{i})=f(t_{i+1})-f(t_{i})
$$
for **some** $s_{i}\in[t_{i},t_{i+1}].$ But why is the **inequality** there?

Comment: You're right it should be equality and the next equality where he used the max is in fact an inequality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Mean Value Theorem we have that for some $s_i \in [t_i, t_{i+1}]$

$$\begin{align} f(t_{i+1}) - f(t_i) = f'(s_i) (t_{i+1} - t_i)  &\implies (f(t_{i+1}) - f(t_i))^2 = (f'(s_i) (t_{i+1} - t_i))^2 \\&\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n}(f(t_{i+1}) - f(t_i))^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(f'(s_i) (t_{i+1} - t_i))^2\\&\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n}(f(t_{i+1}) - f(t_i))^2 \color{#05f}\leq \color{red}{\max_{0\leq s \leq T} \{f'^2(s)\}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (t_{i+1} - t_i))^2 \\ &= \ldots\end{align}$$